# Convert a dataframe to a list and arrange output as text in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am still new to RMarkdown and I am trying to learn few tweaks but I have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
dat <- data.frame(
  counties=c("greg county","cupe county","Bule county","Jojo county","rofe county"), 
  cases = c(70,98,69,430,56)
)
```

This table is generated from some statistical calculations  and instead of displaying it as a table in RMarkdown report, I did like to convert it to a list and display the results in a text. This is an example of what I mean:

**Desired output**

```
Cases per county: greg county - 70 cupe county - 98 Bule county - 69 Jojo county - 430
                  rofe county - 56
```

How can I go around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `paste()` function to concatenate strings, and `apply()` to iterate over the rows of the data frame.

```
output_string <- apply(dat, 1, function(row){
  paste(row['counties'], "-", row['cases'], sep = " ")
})
output_string <- paste(output_string, collapse = " ")
cat("Cases per county:", output_string)
```

Output:

```
Cases per county: greg county -  70 cupe county -  98 Bule county -  69 Jojo county - 430 rofe county -  56
```

Comment: Looks good, is there a possible way that I  can bolden the values from cases, like have a county name greg county with bold 70?

Answer (score 1):

As `paste` is `vectorized`, we could directly apply the `paste` on the columns

```
with(dat, sprintf('Cases per country: %s', paste(counties, cases,
    sep = ' - ', collapse = ' ')))
```

-output

```
[1] "Cases per country: greg county - 70 cupe county - 98 Bule county - 69 Jojo county - 430 rofe county - 56"
```